# SQL Server 2008 - Foreign Key is present but primary key data is not

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008

In SQL Server 2008, I ran into an issue where a foreign key wasn't acting like it should.

These are the 3 tables (simplified) in my database:

- Stations (ID, Name)
- Battalions (ID, Name)
- StationBattalionList (ID, StationID, BattalionID)

`StationBattalionList` has 2 foreign keys: one links the `StationID` to `Stations.ID`, while the other links `BattalionID` to `Battalion.ID`.

Now comes the issue: there are entries in `StationBattalionList` that have a `BattalionID` that no longer exists in the `Battalions` table.

Has anyone ran into an issue before where there is a foreign key present but for some reason the primary key data it is linked to is no longer there? I of course can't recreate it because the constraint errors will pop, but I can't figure out how this occurred in the first place.

Comment: When you create a foreign key, you can specify in SSMS if you want to check existing data or not. I'm guessing that the problem is something like this, though I've never known anyone that changed the default 'yes' to 'no'...

Comment: In addition to checking the values when the FKs were first created, FKs can be disabled by specifying WITH NOCHECK.  In Management studio you can check the status by going to the Keys section for the table, right click "Script Key As.." and see if the create statement has WITH CHECK or WITH NOCHECK.

Comment: When scripting the foreign key, it says WITH CHECK.  We do not use cascade because we don't want anything automatically deleted, we want to have control and the ability to see when something is deleted.  I will find the script that added the foreign key and see if it sheds any light.